# HikariCP and mysql threads_connected

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using Spring Cloud Data Flow and HikariCP. I've set the maximumPoolSize to 5 for HikariCP, but threads_connected shows over 1500.. 
So far I have used

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

which shows over 1500.

I have also used

```
select * from information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
    DB like 'MY_DB%' and (
    HOST like 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX%' or 
    HOST like 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX%'
);
```

to identify the threads are being created on my part.

Aside from maximum-pool-size, I have only set jdbc-url, username, password, and driver-class-name. Do I need anything else?

Comment: show stack trace log. how u know its used 1500 connection pool?\

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib I looked it up using SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';

Comment: then check connecton used by which user. also if there is multiple application who create connection and not close then it will be happend. there is many reason. u need to analyze why this happend.

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib I have used show processlist to identify the threads are all being created on my part.

Comment: show ur hikaricp minimulIdle connection minimum idle timeout. show ur hikaricp properties u used. it will help to identify the reason why connection pool size increase

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib They were all left blank, so they are at default. minimumIdle at 5 and idleTimeout at 10mins.